# HTML5 framework for both Web and Mobile (LAMP)

Tags: javascript, html, sencha-touch, lamp

Which are the possible options for HTML5 framework which support both web and mobile development. For example, if I have to develop a application for web which is 100% iPad or Android tabs compatible (with touch, slide support) then what should be the ideal choice in LAMP environment.

I have heard of Sencha which looks like HTML5 mobile only framework. Please correct me if that's not the case.

Comment: if you just look at the sencha page you'll see there are 2 main frameworks the mobile one and Extjs web framework. there are no silverbullets,  desktop dev is different from mobile developpement. Also , we dont know what kind of "HTML5" app you are developping. javascript is not html5  ,neither is mobile developpement. touch events are not a standart , media queries are though.

Comment: This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, **polling**, or extended discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery Mobile is a great choice for cross-browser compatibility. In my experience it creates both great-looking mobile sites and desktop sites. It may take a bit of tweaking to get it working the way you want it, but overall I've found it to be the best solution.

www.jquerymobile.com